# mediation analysis with generalized mixed effect model

Tags: r, mediation

I see that is it possible to use lmer() in r and then run mediate(), but our data does not have normal distribution. So I am wondering, is there any way to run glmer() and then do mediation analysis? If not possible in R, any solution in other language?

Comment: I don't use R much anymore, but I strongly suspect that there is a package for this. Maybe [`lavaan`](https://lavaan.ugent.be/index.html)? I know I can build this in [`pymc`](https://www.pymc.io/welcome.html).

Comment: Lavaan seems to work. I will look into the ducumentations. Thank you so much!